# Can I install Indy for delphi xe6?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe6

I have to make a cross platform application. I read that Indy is a cross platform socket library.
Can I install indy for delphi xe6?

Comment: Have you tried to install Delphi for XE6?

Answer (score 3):

Indy is pre-installed in every version of Delphi since v6. You can use the bundled Indy version as-is, or consider [upgrading it](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) as there have been updates to Indy since XE6 was released.

Comment: but how can I start using the preinstalled version?

Comment: Indy is pre-installed, just use its components like any other. Drop them on your Form at design-time. There are several Indy pages in the Tool Palette. Or create the components in code at run-time. Your choice.  Indy has many components available, but you did not say what kind of cross-platform tool you want to make, or what protocol(s) you want to work with.

Comment: and the most import an can I use indy for a mac application? thank you in advace!

Comment: the main reason is: I have a mac application and this application should communicate with a window service. I used socket (TServer socket and TClient socket) but then I came up with the idea that this is used only in windows.

Comment: @programingdelphi Yes, Indy is supported on the Mac. You could have found this out by a simple websearch, or even attempting to use Indy on Mac.

Comment: @programingdelphi: Indy supports FireMonkey, and is available for every platform that FireMonkey supports. That includes OSX.

Comment: How can I set up a connection between TIdTcpServer and TIdTcpClient  so that the client sends a string to the server?

Comment: Assign an IP/Port to the `TIdTCPServer.Bindings` collection and set its `Active` property to true. Then set the client's `Host` and `Port` properties and call its `Connect()` method. Use the various `TIdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write...()` methods to send data to the server. In the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event, use the various `TIdContext.Connection.IOHandler.Read...()` methods to read data from the client.